# jQuery FadeTo doesn't work when going back to original div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I thought it'd be a fun project to develop slider functionality that fades from one div to the next at an automatic interval. It works! But for some reason when it goes back to the first slide, the fading animation simply stops working, but resumes working when it advances to the next slide and beyond. It's only with switching from the last to the first slide that the animation fails. It doesn't make sense to me because other than the index, the code for advancing and restarting are both essentially identical.

I've tried z-index, I've tried using hide/show in conjunction with FadeTo, I've tried a combination of all three. Doesn't seem to lick the problem.

I added code to output to console to see what was going wrong, and I don't see any issues. I'm sure it's something subtle but crucial -- but it's continuing to elude me. So any insight is certainly appreciated!

The code and working example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/cawwM/

This is the function that does the slide toggling:

```
    function toggleSlides(slideArray) {
        var currentSlideIndex = 0;
        var slideLength = slideArray.length;
        window.console&&console.log('Slide Toggle interval fired. \n');
        window.console&&console.log('Searching for current slide... \n');
        $.each(slideArray,function(index, value){ 
            if($('#'+value).hasClass('currentSlide') === true) {
                currentSlideIndex = index;
                window.console&&console.log('Current slide identified. \n');
                return (false); // break loop, we have index.
            }
        });
        if(currentSlideIndex < slideLength - 1) {
            // Advance to next slide
            window.console&&console.log('Still more slides ('+currentSlideIndex+' < '+(slideLength - 1)+'). Advancing to next slide now. \n');
            $('#'+slideArray[currentSlideIndex]).removeClass('currentSlide');
            $('#'+slideArray[currentSlideIndex+1]).addClass('currentSlide');
            $('element').css('z-index', 9999);
            $('#'+slideArray[currentSlideIndex+1]).show().fadeTo('slow', 1, function() {
                $('#'+slideArray[currentSlideIndex]).fadeTo(0, 0).hide().css('z-index', 1);
            }).css('z-index', 5);
        } else {
            // Go back to the first slide
            window.console&&console.log('No further slides, going back to first slide now. \n');
            $('#'+slideArray[currentSlideIndex]).removeClass('currentSlide');
            $('#'+slideArray[0]).addClass('currentSlide');
            $('#'+slideArray[0]).show().fadeTo('slow', 1, function() {
                $('#'+slideArray[currentSlideIndex]).fadeTo(0, 0).hide().css('z-index', 1);
            }).css('z-index', 5);
        }
        window.console&&console.log('Done with slide toggling. \n');
    }
```

Once again, feedback is always appreciated! If you see a way I can improve my code, that'd also be appreciated -- I'm always keen to improve my skills by learning better methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this line, the line before `Done with slide toggling`

```
$('#'+slideArray[currentSlideIndex]).fadeTo(0, 0).hide().css('z-index', 1);
```

Remove the `hide()` method and apply the `slow` effect.

```
$('#'+slideArray[currentSlideIndex]).fadeTo('slow', 0).css('z-index', 1);
```

By Removing the `hide()` it will not hide the last slide immediately

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cawwM/1/)

Comment: That works, but it has the side effect of causing the DIV layer to remain active even though it's hidden (opacity set to via FadeTo). The end result is that the link on the hidden div will remain active and override the current slide's link -- indicative that the hidden div remains on top of the current slide.

An ideal solution would be for the div to remove itself (example: hide() does display: none; which eliminates that issue). Although using hide() eliminates that animation. So you see the quandary I'm in.

Comment: Figured out a solution. You got me on the right track, so I started thinking. It hit me: fadeOut will fade it and set the display to none -- two birds with one stone. So I replaced fadeTo('slow', 0) with fadeOut('slow'). That got it working correctly. I updated the fiddle. See: http://jsfiddle.net/cawwM/2/  -- Since you got me on the right path so I was able to find the right solution, I'm marking your answer as the solution. Thanks for your help!